# Adding a loading indicator to form submission module

Tags: webforms

I have a custom module that is altering a webform to add custom submission handling using:

```
$form['#submit'][]='paymentComplete';
```

From the time the user clicks the submit button, until the paymentComplete() function completes it takes 2-3 seconds, but the user experience doesn't really indicate what is going on. How can I add some type of 'waiting indicator' that starts right BEFORE the request to execute paymentComplete()?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there are no OOTB features in Drupal yet but perhaps you can implement ProgressButtonStyles by Codrops. See https://github.com/codrops/ProgressButtonStyles for more info...